# Error putting S3 policy: MalformedPolicy: Policy has an invalid condition key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am getting error on running terraform plan "Error putting S3 policy: MalformedPolicy: Policy has an invalid condition key"

Below is the condition that I added:

```
Condition = {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm": "AES256",
          "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key": "*",
          "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key-MD5": "*"
        }
      }
```

Comment: Please add the entire code block where this happens.

Comment: I don't think `"*"` is a valid value for a `StringNotEquals` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Condition = {
  "StringNotEquals": {
    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm": "AES256"
  }
}
```